# Condition Error

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

i am trying to have a check on that if value is null then don't show the message and recall the constructor, i did the following way but its not working.

```
if (title == null) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter All Values");
        new InfoFrame();

    } 
    else {

        try {
            System.out.println(title+""+date);
            System.out.println(title+""+date);

            s.execute("INSERT INTO task ([title],[deadline],[priority],[time]) VALUES ('"+ title+ "','"+ date+ "','"+ priority  + "','"+ time + "')");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Task has been added to the Database:");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

*Edited the `var Title` like stupid naming conventions

Comment: I'm sure it *is* working. I'm sure null checking is fine. What other info do you have, and have you tried a debugger ?

Comment: "its not working" is *never* enough detail. And including values in the SQL is almost *never* appropriate (use parameterized SQL).

Comment: Your sql query is an candidate for SQL injection attacks, use parameterized query...

Comment: @BrianAgnew i tried debugger and i see the value of `Title=""`

Comment: Then check if the title is `null` or empty.

Comment: @JonSkeet 
Please can you show how to do it appropriately

Comment: @Laf `Title` is a string and if user dont input anything then it shows its values in debugger like that `Title=""`

Comment: Which is an empty string. so in your `if` statement you can check for `if (Title == null || Title.isEmpty ())`. I advise you to stick to Java naming conventions. Having variable names with a capital letter as the first letter is non standard.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Title.isEmpty()) {
```

Will do the trick.

If you want to check both null or empty

```
if (Title == null || Title.isEmpty()) {
```

Also its better to start your variable in simple letters.

Comment: Since the rest of his code is missing, I don't think we can assume that `Title` will never be `null`, so I would check for `null` first, then check if the string is empty.